# How to upgrade log4j in 3rd party jar used as dependency in project pom?

Tags: log4j, eclipse-rcp, pom.xml, log4j2, jericho-html-parser

We use jericho 3.3 that has log4j 1.2.17 as transitive dependency. We plan to upgrade to 2.17.1 for all 3rd party as well as direct dependencies. Jericho 3.4 the latest has log4j api 2.4, how can we achieve to log4j api 2.17.1 ?

Comment: It's under an Open Source license. Have you considered contributing a patch updating their dependency?

Comment: What is your build tool? Maven? Gradle? Something else?